# NPM commands aren't giving any response at all

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed the latest version of Node.js. And on PowerShell, giving the command = node -v

then the output I get = v18.14.0

but when I give the,
command = npm -v

then the output I get = nothing, it just moves to the next line, as no input has given. Like PowerShell is not recognizing the npm command that was given.

Check the below ss.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEega.png)

And also it is like PowerShell is not recognizing any npm commands at all and I have tried bunch of other npm commands, there is no response and it just moves the other line. Just like the ss above.

and when I give the following command in visual studio code the result is same, but also another weird things happens in visual studio code.

command = node -v, then the output = v18.14.0, ss also attached for reference[node -v command in vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2i1w.png).

command = npm -v, then the output is just the path:

Directory: C:\Users\subha\OneDrive\Desktop\CSS Projects\Advanced CSS and Sass Flexbox, Grid, Animations and More\starter

this whole path just moves to upper left corner of the terminal in the visual studio code and also the command given cursor also moves in the middle of the path. Attached ss below for reference.[npm -v command in vsc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8iN8.png)

Additional info:

(1) Command prompt is not working, as soon I opened by double clicking on cmd. It displayed for half a second and then disappears immediately automatically. Don't know whether this is related problem or not?

(2) Have tried and reinstalled node.js 3 or 4 times but the same issue is there.

(3) Have changed the "Environment Variable" and added the path to where node.js is installed. Added both " C:\Program Files\nodejs  " and also
" C:\Users\subha\AppData\Roaming\npm "

Comment: Run `where npm` in an admin cmd prompt and share output

Comment: cmd is not working at all. It opens up and closed automatically.

Comment: so I'm using powershell as in admin and after using command where npm nothing is happening. Please help

Answer (score 0):

So since `where npm` does not respond but neither throws error, it probably has to do with `env variables`

To add `npm` to your env variables:
Open `Start` > Search for `env` > Edit `System environment variables` > `Environment Variables` > Under system environment variables select `PATH` > Click edit > Add new > Enter the location of your npm installation.

In my case it's: `C:\Users\<NAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm` or `%appdata%/npm`